# Rails как реализовать форму для добавления записи в join таблицу

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Доброго времени суток.
 У меня есть две модели Payment и Material связанные между собой через модель MaterialPayment. Связь has_many :through.

Payment.rb

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :material_payments
  has_many :materials, through: :material_payments

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :material_payments, allow_destroy: true
  #accepts_nested_attributes_for :materials
end
```

Material.rb

```
class Material < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :material_payments
  has_many :payments, through: :material_payments
end
```

material_payment.rb

```
class MaterialPayment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :payment
  belongs_to :material
end

class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_payment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /payments
  # GET /payments.json
  def index
    @payments = Payment.all
    @materials = Material.all
    @payment = Payment.new
    @payment.material_payments.build
  end

  # GET /payments/1
  # GET /payments/1.json
  def show
    @material_payments = MaterialPayment.where(payment_id: @payment)
  end

  # GET /payments/new
  def new
    @payment = Payment.new
  end

  # GET /payments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /payments
  # POST /payments.json
  def create
    @payment = Payment.new(payment_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @payment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @payment, notice: 'Payment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @payment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @payment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /payments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /payments/1.json
  def update
    #@payment = Payment.find(params[:id])
    #@payment.material_payments.update_all(payment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @payment.update(payment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @payment, notice: 'Payment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @payment }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @payment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /payments/1
  # DELETE /payments/1.json
  def destroy
    @payment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to payments_url, notice: 'Payment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_payment
      @payment = Payment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def payment_params
      params.require(:payment).permit(:client_address,
                                      :client_name,
                                      :client_payment,
                                      :client_description,
                                      :client_new_connection,
                                      :material_ids => [],
                                      :material_payments_attributes => [:material_id, :payment_id, :quantity])
    end
end
```

В таблице MaterialPayment есть поле quantity. Записи создаются через Payment. В таблице Material есть некоторое количество материалов из которых необходимо сделать выбор через checkbox. Т.е. если галочка стоит, то добавляется запись в таблицу MaterialPayment (payment_id + material_id + quantity).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема заключается в том, что никак не могу понять как сделать форму, чтобы можно было добавлять запись во вложенную таблицу.

Пока удалось сделать путем принудительного добавления атрибутов в форме:

```
= f.fields_for :material_payments do |mp|
            #material_link_1
              = check_box_tag 'payment[material_payments_attributes][1][material_id]', 1
              = label_tag 'payment[material_payments_attributes][1][material_id]', @materials.find(1).material_name
            #material_1
              = mp.number_field :quantity,
                                hide_label: true,
                                append: 'м.'
```

Записи добавляются нормально, но это ведь неправильный подход. И сейчас при редактировании записи, получается что срабатывает не метод update, а создается новая запись в таблицу MaterialPayment...

Подскажите, пожалуйста, хоть в каком направлении копать?

Спасибо.

Comment: Какие есть поля в таблице `material_payments`? В частности, есть ли там первичный ключ?

Comment: Ну собственно все которые прописал: :material_id, :payment_id, :quantity

Comment: То есть, там нет `id`?

Comment: Есть, конечно. Его обязательно тоже прописывать? Не знал...

Comment: А что не так с `mp.check_box :material_id`?

Comment: Теоретически должно работать. Я так пробовал. Ошибок не показывает, страница генерится. но и не показывает вообще ни одного поля (((

Comment: Попробовал поработать с предложенным Вами методом. Вроде бы получилось, но только с одной записью из модели Material. Т.е. ко всем остальным записям добавляются атрибуты с одинаковым id и name: <input name="payment[material_payments_attributes][0][material_id]" id="payment_material_payments_attributes_0_material_id" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">